# NoClassDefFound error on running the quickblox app

Tags: java, android, quickblox

I wrote this small code to check the quickblox. Which just registers a user on pressing register button. But when I run this code, i get an error in logcat saying NoClassDefFound 
for QBSettings and hence the application crashes. I've already added the jar file provided by quickblox as an external jar. So, i cant figure out why is this happening? Need Help!

```
import com.quickblox.core.QBCallbackImpl;
import com.quickblox.core.QBSettings;
import com.quickblox.core.result.Result;
import com.quickblox.module.users.QBUsers;
import com.quickblox.module.users.model.QBUser;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button login,register;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(<app-id>, <authkey>, <authsecret>); // error here

    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

    register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final QBUser user = new QBUser("something", "somepassword");

            // register user
            QBUsers.signUp(user, new QBCallbackImpl() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Result result) {
                    // result comes here
                    // check if result success
                    if (result.isSuccess()) {
                        // do stuff you need
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem isn't in your code, it is in your project configuration.
I suppose that you are using Eclipse IDE and you forgot to check quickblox-android.jar file to be included into apk file. Look at step 5 in [this tutorial](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Eclipse_IDE).